# Batch file test for path + file name with extension

Tags: windows-7, batch, batch-file

Batch file in Windows 7.

I want to know how to test for a path + file name with an extension, if it exists or not.

I have tried if exists "myfile.ext"  It seems not to see the file.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is `EXIST`, not "exists".

From `if /?`:

```
EXIST filename    Specifies a true condition if the specified filename
                  exists.
```

Example:

`if exist "myfile.txt" echo Found!`

And you can just add a path as needed:

`if exist "c:\Some folder\myfile.txt" echo Found!`